# The ipa built with Xcode14 ( beta 5 or RC ) is not uploading to Testflight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, ipa, xcode14

The ipa built with **Xcode14** ( **beta5** or **RC** ) is not uploading to Testflight *today*. It worked with Xcode14beta5 last week. I am using Jenkins to upload. Is anyone else experiencing the same ? How do you resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

beta version can't upload apps, you need update xcode to release version